# Box-api simple uploader

Tags: box-api

I'm writing some new apps that will run on Windows (desktop mode, not store app/windows phone).

I’d like for my applications to be able to upload some files to Box anonymously, or with a single hard-coded username and password. Is there an easy way to do this with Box-api? Do I have to go through Oauth2 to do simple uploading?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to use OAuth 2, and additionally will need a Box account for every user of your service.